# Odd or even function?

Tags: functions

Is the function $f(x)=-1$ for $-\pi$ to $0$ and $x$ from $0$ to $\pi$ odd or even?

How do I determine this for this function?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to check how $f(-x)$ and $f(x)$ compare for any given $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$. So consider the cases $x\in [-\pi,0]$ and $x\in [0,\pi]$ separately.

Comment: @Travis This is standard stuff. Even means $f(-x)=f(x)$. Odd means $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: @ Prahlad Vaidyanathan: when i do that I get that the function is neither odd nor even but when i compared with someone else's answer they got it to be even

Comment: @user134785 So at least one of you two has a wrong answer. But yours is fine

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**:

- if $f(-x)=f(x)$, $f$ is even;
- if $f(-x)=-f(x)$, $f$ is odd;
- if neither, $f$ has no definite parity.